# Is it possible to create a cluster in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cluster

I Know how to create a clustering servive in windows 2003 server. Is it possible to create the same in windows 7 too..

Comment: Can you give us *anything* more to work with? This is so vague that we can't even tell if we should move it to serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use the server version of Windows 7 which is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition or Datacenter Edition.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Microsoft Clustering Services no, as the other chaps state that's a feature of the server code. But then you're not that clear what sort of cluster you want - there are lots of other types of clusters you see, you might want this machine to be part of a render-farm cluster - you can do that with W7, or a non-MS DB cluster, again you can do that with W7.

So basically it all comes down to what exactly you're looking to achieve, not the specific technologies you can or can't use, come back to us with more information.

Answer (score 1):

No. Windows 7 is a desktop operating system, it does not support clustering.